# Phonegap Device Ready Listener

Tags: cordova

I am attempting to customize the backButton action using phonegap. The body of my html index doc looks simply as follows.

```
<body onLoad="onLoadData()">
```

I then try to set up deviceready listener and then the backbutton listener. On a backbutton press, the code never reaches the set backbutton listener. I am wondering if anyone knows why this is not working.

```
function onLoadData(){
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
  $.mobile.changePage("#login");
}
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonClick, false);
}
function backButtonClick(){
    var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    console.log("Reached here : " + activePage);
}
```

Comment: Try removing the parenthesis from the "onDeviceReady" function passed to the "addEventListener" call.

Answer (score 0):

`onDeviceReady` will not be called because of how it is set in the listener. As noted in the comments, change:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
```

to:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Comment: I made that change...but it did not fix my problem. Code in backButtonClick is still not being reached

Comment: In my app, I set the listener right after the listener for `deviceready` not in `onDeviceReady`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

You have added `cordova.js` correctly right!
If so,then you can try this. Add the event listener just after script tag, outside of the `onLoadData` method. There is no need for declaring it inside `onLoadData`

```
<script>


 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", backButtonClick, false);

    $.mobile.changePage("#login");
}
function backButtonClick(){
    var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id');
    console.log("Reached here : " + activePage);
}


</script>
```

And as Dawson mentioned, remember to remove `()` from onDeviceReady call.

Comment: the cordova.js file is in the platform_www folder under platforms/android, which is where im running my phonegap app. Is this correct

Comment: yes path is correct. You need to add this line in your code `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` @user3680411